# Migrating from @include to @use/@forward variable issue

Tags: css, webpack, sass

I am trying to start using `@use` and `@forward` instead of `@include` but I am running into an issue with getting the variables to be found. I have the following folder structure:

```
sass/styles.scss
sass/components/_index.scss
sass/components/_general.scss
sass/config/_index.scss
sass/config/_colors.scss
```

In the `sass/styles.scss` file I have

```
@use "config";
@use "components";
```

In the `sass/components/_index.scss` file I have

```
@forward "general";
```

In the `sass/components/_general.scss` file I have

```
body {
    color: config.$brand-text;
}
```

In the `sass/config/_index.scss` file I have

```
@forward "colors";
```

In the `sass/config/_colors.scss` file I have

```
$brand-text: #f0f0f0;
```

When I try to run Webpack using dart-sass I get the following error

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: There is no module with the namespace "config".
  ╷
3 │   color: config.$brand-text;
  │          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵ 
sass/components/_structure.scss 3:10  @use
sass/components/_index.scss 3:1       @use
Sites/test/sass/styles.scss 2:1
```

If I move the body css to the `styles.scss` file everything compiles fine. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which version of sass are you using? `node-sass`?

Comment: I am using sass 1.26.8
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass